# Liouville measure in the energy level

Tags: classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry

Again banged my head trying to make sense of the Mechanics course and hit a rock bottom with another problem. I would really appreciate the step by step explanation  for the results of it.

We have a symplectic manifold (M, ω), a Hamilton function H : M -> $\mathbb{R}$ and c a regular value of H and consider the level $E_c := H^{-1}(c)$.

a) Show that $E_c$ is a manifold and give its dimension. Also show that for any $x\in E_c$ the tangent space at $E_c$ is given by $T_xE_c = kerdH_x$

From this we are given the following facts: let the Liouville volume 2n-form 
 $\Omega$:= $\omega \wedge \omega \wedge...\wedge \omega$ the n-fold
wedge product. The flow $\phi^t$ of the Hamiltonian vector field $X_H$ preserves 
$\Omega$. Also, the level $E_c$ is preserved by the same $\phi^t$. 
,Consider $x\in E_c$ and tangent vectors $\xi_1, \xi_2; ...\xi_{2n-1} \in T_xE_c$; having to define $ \Omega_{c,x}(\xi_1, \xi_2; ...\xi_{2n-1})$
To this end we write the equation
$ \Omega_{x}(\eta, \xi_1, \xi_2; ...\xi_{2n-1}) = dH_x(\eta)\wedge \Omega_{c,x}(\xi_1, \xi_2; ...\xi_{2n-1})  $, $\eta \in T_xM$ is arbitrary.

b)Show that this equation determines $\Omega$ in a unique way, independent of $\eta$

c)Also show that $\Omega_c$ is a nondegenerate (2n-1) form, i.e. a volume form
on $E_c$

d) Finally show that $\phi^t|E_c$ preserves $\Omega_c$

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What have you tried? 
Do you know the implicit function theorem? (a) is immediate from that.

Comment: I manage to solve everything up until c, but I don't know how the restriction from d) works

Comment: For that, you check that $\phi^t$ preserves $dH$. You've been told that $\phi^t$ preserves $\Omega$ (or you can check it easily). You also need to verify that if $\eta$ is transverse to $E_c$, then so is $\phi^t_* \eta$. Point (d) now involves a little calculation, but the ingredients are what I just enumerated.

Comment: Perfect. This helped a lot. Thank you :)